# python for and while loop for tuples

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, tuples

I'm a beginner in python and was wondering why this function doesn't work. It is syntactically correct.

This function is supposed to collect every odd tuple item and I used a for loop as follows:

```
def oddTuples(aTup):

    result = ()

    for i in aTup:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            result += (aTup[i],) 

    return result
```

This is the 'correct' answer using while loop.

```
def oddTuples(aTup):

    # a placeholder to gather our response
    rTup = ()
    index = 0

    # Idea: Iterate over the elements in aTup, counting by 2
    #  (every other element) and adding that element to 
    #  the result
    while index < len(aTup):
        rTup += (aTup[index],)
        index += 2

    return rTup
```

If anybody can help me, it would be much appreciated!

UPDATE

Okay, I got the problem, by 'i' I was merely collecting the real value within that tuple. I've fixed that, but this code is catching only some of the odd-idexed items, not all of them....

```
def oddTuples(aTup):
    result = ()
    for i in aTup:
        index = aTup.index(i)   
        if index % 2 == 0:
            result += (aTup[index],)
    return result
```

Comment: _"It is syntactically correct."_ - Just because the parser accepts your program doesn't mean it will work. There can still be problems in the _logic_ of the program, and thus cause run-time errors and bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't catch it on one go since it was *syntactically correct* too, but the error you are having is due to you iterating over the `objects` of the tuple (`aTup`) and not the indices. See here:

```
for i in aTup: # <-- For each *object* in the tuple and NOT indices
    if i % 2 == 0:
        result += (aTup[i],)
```

To fix the problem, use `range()` and `len()` over the `aTup` so that it iterates over the indices of the tuple instead, and change the `if` statement accordingly:

```
for i in range(len(aTup)):
    if aTup[i] % 2 == 0:
        result += (aTup[i],)
```

An alternative solution is to keep your object iterations but append the object directly to the `result` tuple instead of indexing:

```
for i in aTup:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        result += (i,)
```

Hope ths helped!

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is iterating over the values in aTup, not the index of the values.

It appears your want your code to iterate over the index of the values or through a range of numbers starting with 0 and ending with the length of the tuple minus one and then use that number as the index to pull the value out of the tuple.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you are not using index..In below code i is not an index but the element in tuple but you are calling aTup[i] assuming i is an index which is not.
The below code will work fine - No need of doing aTup[i] or range.

```
def oddTuples(aTup):
    result = ()
    for i in aTup:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            result += (i,) 
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

In simple words , if your tuple is

```
tup = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5 , 1000);
```

When your code is checking if **each item is % 2 == 0 or not** which is not what you want, from your description , you want only the items with odd **index**

So if you try the tuple above , you will get the following error:
`IndexError: tuple index out of range` , because for the 1000 it satisfy your condition and will do what is said in the if , trying to add the aTup(1000) (element of index 1000 in your input tuple) *which doesn't exist as the tuple is only of 6 elements to your resultTuple*

For this for loop to work , you can use the following method

```
def oddTuples(aTup):
    result = ()
for i in aTup:
    index = tup.index(i) # getting the index of each element
    if index % 2 == 0:
        result += (aTup[index],)
        print(aTup[index])
return result
# Testing the function with a tuple
if __name__ == "__main__":
    tup = (1, 2, 3, 7, 5, 1000, 1022)
    tup_res = oddTuples(tup)
    print(tup_res)
```

The result of this will be

```
1
3
5
1022
(1, 3, 5, 1022)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, due to indentation the code didn't run properly but I understood what you were trying to say! But it still isn't perfectly running..

Comment: @hellocsk most welcome , actually it ran correctly , just check the indentation slowly and you can fix it I am sure :) , I am happy that my answer was clear for you , please vote up if you find my answer helpful (this would really help me) , thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
def oddTuples(aTup):
    result = ()
    for i in aTup:
        index = aTup.index(i)   
        if index % 2 == 0:
            result += (aTup[index],)
    return result
```

With

```
def oddTuples(aTup):
    result = ()
    for i in aTup:
        index = aTup.index(i)   
        result += (aTup[index],)
    return result
```

To fix you issue of it only doing the even numbered ones.